# Shorthand method to count length of array

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have an array like this

```
var arr = [{a:1, ...},{a:1, ...},{c:2, ...},{a:3, ...},{a:1, ...}]
```

how can I get the length of array where `arr[x].a != 1` .

I know this can be done using `for loop` and `push` but I want to follow the best practise as every decent programmer should do.

**P.S** FYI I am using AngularJS.

**EDIT 1**
**For anyone facing issues with `arrow function` in [sajeetharan's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47324559/6919688) answer because of ES6 script here is the solution**

```
arr.filter(function(a){return a.a != 1}).length;
```

Comment: Regarding your edit, what browser/environment are you using? arrow notation has been supported by pretty much every modern browser for a while now (with the exception of IE11 I guess)

Comment: I am developing android app using Ionic framework. Arrow function is not working in my case thats why I came with the workaround.

Comment: if you're building it as an application, you may want to look into a build automation tool like [webpack](https://webpack.js.org) paired with babel (with minimal transformations). It will let you write modern JavaScript regardless of the platform. You can transpile your JS to older versions to target specific platforms (although hopefully you won't have to target the older engines for long).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use **[`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)** and **[`length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length)**

```
const result = arrayToCount.filter(i => i.a != 1 ).length;
```

As **`@Naman Kheterpal`** mentioned below, Another way is to use **[`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)**

```
const result = arrayToCount.reduce((c, o) => o + (o.a === 1), 0)
```

Answer (score 17):

The most memory efficient way for this is:

```
const result = arr.reduce((count,el)=> count+ (el.a!==1)},0)
```

`filter` creates a complete new array, `reduce` only creates a new var.
And both of them iterates over the array once.

Comment: If you're using arrow notation and immediately returning, you might as well just simplify: `arr.reduce((c, o) => (o.a === 1 ? c : ++c), 0)`

Comment: @noahnu : `arr.reduce((c, o) => o + (o.a === 1), 0)` ;-)

Comment: @LeonAdler yes, though it should be `c + (o.a !== 1)`.

Answer (score 15):

You can use `array.prototype.filter` and `array.length`:

```
var length = arr.filter(el => el.a !== 1).length
```